What might cause excess counts in the first few bins of the histogram of muon decay times?
I did a measurement of atmospheric muons lifetime using a plastic scintillator, connected to a PMT with adjutable High voltage, a discriminator with a thershold voltage and an FPGA timer.
I was told by the instructor that I need to throw the first one or two bins but didn't provide a detailed explanation that I can write in my report.
Does anyone have insights (with refferences please) on this?



you're link doesn't work, but who wants links. Can you describe the experiment? "a" scintillator seems light on equipment. Are these from cosmic rays?

@JEB Yes, I edited the question.

and it got you an answer ;-)

Not really an answer (especially not at the quality of actual experimentalists :)) but just a general comment that the "edge" bins of an instrument tend to be less trustworthy then bins in the middle. Basically, because any instrument is going to have physical limitations that limit its sensitivity. If the edge bins weren't near those limitations, then the manufacturer could expand the range of the instrument without losing sensitivity, and sell it for more :) Like I said, this isn't a serious answer, just some general intuition to keep in mind.

Your diagram suggests that you are observing the decays of muons which stop in your plastic scintillator. So you should observe a scintillation pulse when the muon enters the scintillator, and another pulse when the muon's decay creates a fast electron.
Every pulse detector system has some "dead time" after seeing one pulse when it is not sensitive to other pulses.  For example, your electron might appear while the muon signal in your photomultiplier is still decaying.  You, with an oscilloscope, might be able to distinguish a "double-humped" photomultiplier signal from a single pulse, but your discriminator is stupider than you are. The logic pulse out of your discriminator has some finite duration, so your dead time can be no briefer than the discriminator width.
Actually measuring dead time is tricky, because it's a little probabilistic. But if you can establish that the dead time is "much" shorter than the 2.2 microsecond half-life, you can fit the exponential distribution from the long tail and just exclude the funny-looking bins from the short-time end of the distribution.
If you have extra counts in the early bins, you probably have something in your electronics that is oscillating or otherwise bouncing, so that a single pulse registers twice.  I don't think I can give you a detailed diagnosis without actually seeing your setup in person. But, as a commenter points out, it's not unusual for an apparatus to have poor calibration right at the edges of its sensitivity range. It's also not unusual, especially for a student lab, to throw out earliest or latest measurements with no more explanation than that you feel squicky about them. That emotional argument wouldn't fly for a PhD thesis, where you would instead have to do supplementary experiments to figure out why your detector system fell apart at short times. But you aren't writing a PhD thesis on this muon lifetime experiment.
The histogram you added in v7 of your question is beautiful.  I suggest you replot with Poissonian $\sqrt N$ error bars ($400\pm20$, $100\pm10$, etc., but your computer does the arithmetic) and plot on a log scale. I think you'll see a nice straight line, the logarithm of your nice exponential, but it'll be easier to see which early bins are funky, and which late bins are buried in random background.
A simple way to justify excluding early or late time bins is to do your curve fit with a number of different start and end points, and show that the fit stabilizes once you have excluded enough endpoints, while still of course including most of your data. From eyeballing your figure, I think you'll have events above background out to ten or twelve microseconds, which will be five to seven lifetimes.  (Note: if you have the software for nonlinear fits, do exponential fits to your actual data, rather than linear fits to the logarithm of your data. The log scale is mostly for visualization; fitting to the logarithm gives undue weight to the  late background-only bins.)

Thank you. The dead time of my detector is not after seeing one pulse but rather after a second pulse that stops the timer. The dead time of my detector is 1ms, much longer than the decay times. I didn't understand how exactely the dead time causes a false readings of shorter times, what do you mean by muon signal is still decaying? And by "double humped" signal you mean two signals that are close in time? What do you mean by exclude the funny-looking bins from the short-time end of the distribution? Do you reffer to the first few bins I was told to disgard?

Ok I understand that the reset time is not what you meant by dead time, but rather the short time between two pulses that below it the detector cannot distinguish two pulses. So how does this creats excess readings? As I see it, this phenomana can eliminate readings of lifetimes smaller than dead time, thus increasing the portion of longer lifetimes in the measurements and distorting the histogram in the long-time tail of the histofram.

And also, is there a refference you might know that contains the explanation you gave me? Tried to search myself and even tried perplexity, I see nothing about dead time causing excess readings in the short time frames.

Dead time makes missing pulses, not extra pulses. I think I am too rusty to diagnose extra pulses without looking at your setup in person.

If you would like to cite this conversation, there is a "cite" button under the answer.  I learned this stuff mostly hands-on. I vaguely remember having a really excellent book about laboratory technique by Leo or Leon, with great engineering drawings and guidance for building vacuum systems and stuff like that. A search brings up this book by Leo which is approximately the right age, but actually looks more on point for your situation. Remember not to cite sources that you haven't read, or that you haven't read completely.

I confess to having read the text of your question, about throwing away the first few time bins, but apparently not the title, about excess counts in the first few bins. Is this what you actually observe? I would be interested to see your spectrum.

@rob Me too (no hashtag). more information is always better than less (TMI notwithstanding).

@rob I added the histogram. I also saw an article from alabama were students had the same issue and just wrote that the first bin wasn't following an exponential curve so they discarded it. Moreover, I saw another experiment where in the first few bins they had much less counts and they said it was due to muon capture.

@LDBT What a lovely histogram! I extended the answer.

This is not an answer, but a clarification of the already correct answer.
There are multiple dead times. You have that of the physical process of detection (i.e, if it causes voltage to sag), that of the discriminator turning your analog pulse in to a digital "True", and then that of your whole system.
For a few photons, I don't think a PMT has any dead time (I once exposed one to sunlight and the dead time $\rightarrow \infty$).
In a discriminator, you receive an analog input and the device goes high for a time $t_{hi}$.
During that time, you cannot "go hi" again. Here there are two options:

Non updating discriminator: If another event(s) occurs, the discriminator ignores inputs during $t_{hi}$. Since your physical process has an exponential distribution (in time) between events, the number of events occurring during $t_{hi}$ is Poisson distributed, so if you're calculating a cross-section (which requires total-number-of-events) you need to make a correction for missed events. As the even rate increases, the detector is cycling as fast as it can, and dead time correction becomes larger, with large statistical error.

continually updating discriminator: here, a second event occurs and restarts the clock counting $t_{hi}$, so the thing stays high for longer than $t_{hi}$, and all you know is that 2 or more events occurred while it was high. As the event rate increases, the system is just stuck on high, and the experiment doesn't work.


Finally, when you investigate your whole system, you may find other types of dead time--esp if software or firmware gets in the mix.
I worked on a SLAC detector where the correction took months to figure out, and the equation was like 4 pages in LaTex. I wonder if was published somewhere? (NE18- color transparency).

Destroying a single-photon-sensitive PMT by exposing it ordinary light levels is a rite of passage in the business. But "the dead time approached infinity" is my new favorite way to describe the failure.

@rob I was on NE18 and NE17 (a personal "directors discretion" of Burton Richter, my PhD) and we were gifted the famous SLAC "DELCO" phototubes, of which needed to find the best--a total grad student project: here are 200 PMT's, pick the top 20 with regards to noise current: I killed the best one! :-(

@rob But a better PMT fail was on MIT/BATES "SAMPLE", neon had the best index of refraction for pi/e separation--so as a clueless student I built a test Cherenkov detector. Right when I turned it on (at Kellog Rad Lab/Caltech), Val Telegdi was visiting. I describe my plan, and he says in heavy accent: "You put a Nobel gas at high voltage? WTF wrong with you?"...so I look at the oscilloscope expecting to see nice comic ray Poisson distributed pulses and wtf was coming out the backend was pure chaos. So I went on futile attempt to quench it with carbon dioxide. In the end, we used "air".
